# Shortcut to open Android XML layout in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, shortcut

For example, if I had something like

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Would there be a shortcut to open `activity_main.xml`? If not, is there a way to create one?

Comment: what do you mean by "open"? viewing the xml layout in your app or eclipse, rendered or text?

Comment: Viewing the XML in Eclipse as text.

Comment: Its there. Just press `Ctrl` and move the cursor to the word `activity_main` which is in line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` then, it will be give two option that one is for opening xml layout and another one is opening the declaration in `R.java` file. This is the shortcut to open the XML layout easily. Let me know if this work or not?

Comment: +1 for this @SpK. works for me. A time saver!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its there. Just hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and move the cursor to the word `activity_main` which is the line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` then, it will be give two option that one is for opening xml layout and another one is opening the declaration in `R.java` file. This is the shortcut to open the XML layout easily.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

This is not exactly a shortcut, but you can highlight the `activity_main` part on that `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` line and then press **Ctrl+Shift+R**.

The Open Resource dialog that shows up should have `activity_main.xml` (along with other files with `activity_main` in their names) at the top of the list. Just press Enter to open the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its an `id`. When you create an `XML file in android` automatically that file has given an id by Android and you can find it into `gen folder` and the class name is `R.java`. So if you want to see that file you have to open `res folder -> layout folder -> there you can see that xml file`.

But you can do it as **@joe** or **@Spk** has suggested you. And Spk's solution is far better. So cheers.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the class file opened instead of the java file it probably wont work.  But in the java file press control on windows or command on mac and hover over the element for options to navigate.