# Eclipse open declaration (F3) for resources

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

as you know :

In Eclipse when F3 is pressed on a class, its declaration appears.
But if we press F3 on a resource, it opens the R.java and shows resource's ID.

My questions is :

Is there a way to open the resource declaration in the xml file instead of R.java ?
(As on earlier versions of ADT plugin ?)

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/12594145/1023092

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press ctrl and then click on the name of resource it will prompt you to open that resource in related.xml file.

Other think could be as @Roman mentioned but that would not be good if you have same xml file in you project.

Comment: When I do that, it opens the R file instead of the related xml as F3 does. Is there a configuration to change that ?

Comment: it gives option 1. open declaration and 2. Open in corresponding .xml

Comment: It works! But do you know a way to bind this function to a shortcut instead of use the mouse

Comment: On iMac you hold down "cmd" and hoover over the R.string.xyz

Comment: that also shows you options namely "Open Declaration" and "Open Declaration in related.xml"

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can open android resources this way. It is not quite that, but for workaround you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open resource files by name. Very convenient.

Comment: but if in all your projects you have list.xml then you need to manually go to that particular resource file

Comment: thank you, but i already know Ctrl+Shift+R, but as Amit said i you have main.xml in many projects it doesn't work